# Creating the node ids：Is this SQL error related to geometry type？

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I loaded a **multilinestring** layer into PostGIS Manager：

[image]
[image]

and use the SQL query, trying to get the table with the node ids：

```
ALTER TABLE split_4 ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE split_4 ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT assign_vertex_id('split_4', 800, 'geom', 'gid');
```

and got this error：

```
Error: Function StartPoint (geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT gid AS id, StartPoint (geom) AS source, EndPoint (geom) ...
                      ^
HINT: did not comply with the specified name and parameter types of function. You may need to add explicit type conversion.
QUERY: SELECT gid AS id, StartPoint (geom) AS source, EndPoint (geom) as target FROM split_4
CONTEXT: PL / pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 23 at target EXECUTE statement FOR
```

Is this error related to the **multilinestring** geometry？

I work under **WIN7-64bits**, with **postgres 8.4**, **pgadmin 3**, **PostGIS 2.0** installed, and download Windows Binaries of **pgrouting**：[pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2.zip](http://www.wiesenhaan.com/pgrouting/pgRouting-1.03_pg-8.4.2.zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems related to PostGIS 2.0

- The function name must be `ST_StartPoint`, missing the "ST_" prefix, which is now required (or you must load `legacy.sql` into your database).
- Geometry type `MULTILINESTRING` cannot be used anymore with `ST_StartPoint` or `ST_EndPoint`.

Comment: I uninstalled PostGIS 2.0, and installed the 1.5 one, it worked!So it does relate to the version of PostGIS.